# Java SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'") gives timezone as IST

Tags: java, date, timezone, date-format, simpledateformat

I have SimpleDateFormat constructor as

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
```

and I am parsing string `"2013-09-29T18:46:19Z".`

I have read that here Z represents the `GMT/UTC` timezone. but when I print this date on console , It prints IST timezne for the returned date.

Now my question is whether my output is right or wrong?

Comment: yes that is what 'Z' represents. Z- Time Zone

Comment: Z = Zulu time => GMT+0, you obviously didn't serve your country ;)

Comment: Please consider changing the accepted answer to that of "AZ_" (== using Instant). If there is library support for this exact use case, why do extra magic?

Answer (score 335, accepted):

You haven't set the timezone only added a `Z` to the end of the date/time, so it will look like a GMT date/time but this doesn't change the value.

Set the timezone to GMT and it will be correct.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Comment: If you have a date, say 2012-12-06T06:00:00 without the Z, does that represent GMT?

Comment: @binarygiant You would have to ask those who sent it.  It could be the local time of the sender.

Comment: Timezone can be set to "UTC"

Comment: Instead of setting the timezone in so many places for different libraries and avoid conflicts with your machine/laptop timezone, you should always set the default timezone of the JVM by setting user.timezone system property:

java -Duser.timezone=GMT ...

Answer (score 124):

`'T'` and `'Z'` are considered here as constants. You need to pass `Z` without the quotes. Moreover you need to specify the timezone in the input string.

Example : `2013-09-29T18:46:19-0700`
And the format  as `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"`

Comment: Subir, Thanks for your answer, but what is "0700" appended to input string??

Comment: `-0700` is the time zone ie -7:00 Hrs

Comment: for -07:00 hour and not -0700 it would be the following:

yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX

Answer (score 65):

**From ISO 8601 String to Java Date Object**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
sdf.parse("2013-09-29T18:46:19Z"); //prints-> Mon Sep 30 02:46:19 CST 2013
```

if you don't set `TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")` then it will output `Sun Sep 29 18:46:19 CST 2013`

**From Java Date Object to ISO 8601 String**

And to convert `Date`object to ISO 8601 Standard (`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'`) use following code

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.US);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));           
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date())); //-prints-> 2015-01-22T03:23:26Z
```

Also note that without `' '` at Z `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` prints `2015-01-22T03:41:02+0000`

Comment: It gives me java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-05-01T18:30:00.000Z" @AZ_

Answer (score 55):

IF you want to handle '[standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15952652/921193)' JSON representation of the Date then better to use this pattern: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"`.

Notice the `X` on the end.  [It will handle timezones in ISO 8601 standard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), and ISO 8601 is exactly what produces this statement in Javascript `new Date().toJSON()`

Comparing to other answers it has some benefits:

1. You don't need to require your clients to send date in GMT
2. You don't need to explicitly convert your Date object to GMT using this: `sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));`

Comment: I am using `play`'s automatic form binding, and use `@Format.DateTime` annotation. Use default pattern with `Z` at ending seem be incorrect. After changed to `X`, it works. Many thanks

Comment: If your date specifies the timezone in an RFC822-compliant fashion like "-0500", this works fine. But for a date such as "2013-07-15T10:22:17-05:00" (also valid ISO8601 TZ) this breaks. In that case you need to use "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX".

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX" should be the exact answer.  2013-09-29T18:46:19Z is ok. 'Z' = UTC = +00 = +0000=+00:00

Answer (score 40):

## tl;dr

The other Answers are outmoded as of Java 8.

```
Instant                           // Represent a moment in UTC. 
.parse( "2013-09-29T18:46:19Z" )  // Parse text in standard ISO 8601 format where the `Z` means UTC, pronounces “Zulu”.
.atZone(                          // Adjust from UTC to a time zone. 
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" )
)                                 // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
```

## ISO 8601

Your string format happens to comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. This standard defines sensible formats for representing various date-time values as text.

## java.time

The old `java.util.Date`/`.Calendar` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` classes have been supplanted by the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). **Avoid the old classes** as they have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome.

Part of the poor design in the old classes has bitten you, where the `toString` method applies the JVM's current default time zone when generating a text representation of the date-time value that is actually in UTC (GMT); well-intentioned but confusing.

The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating textual representations of date-time values. So no need to specify a parsing pattern.

An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2013-09-29T18:46:19Z" );
```

You can apply a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) as needed to produce a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( zoneId );
```

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

Answer (score 34):

and if you don't have the option to go on java8 better use 
'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX**XX**' as this gets correctly parsed again (while with only one X this may not be the case... depending on your parsing function)

X generates: +01

XXX generates: +01:00

Comment: This really helpful. I'm using the date with this format 2021-04-25T11:12:45+00:00 and this XXX has helped :)

Answer (score 10):

## `'Z'` is not the same as `Z`

`'Z'` is just a character literal whereas `Z` is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

Therefore, ***do not use `'Z'` in pattern*** for parsing/formatting.

### The `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API

The modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards. The Date-Time string, `2013-09-29T18:46:19Z` conforms to ISO 8601 standards.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.parse("2013-09-29T18:46:19Z");
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2013-09-29T18:46:19Z");
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("2013-09-29T18:46:19Z");

        System.out.println(instant);
        System.out.println(odt);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2013-09-29T18:46:19Z
2013-09-29T18:46:19Z
2013-09-29T18:46:19Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/yrcEY2)

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline in [UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc). The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for a zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

**Note#1:** In case you need to find out what date and time an `Instant` represents in a particular timezone, you can use [`Instant#atZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-) e.g. the following code will print the date and time this `Instant` in India:

```
ZonedDateTime zdtIndia = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
System.out.println(zdtIndia);
```

You can even convert an object of `ZonedDateTime` from one timezone to another using [`ZonedDateTime#withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-) e.g. the following code will convert `zdt` to an object of `ZonedDateTime` representing date and time in India:

```
ZonedDateTime zdtIndia = zdt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
System.out.println(zdtIndia);
```

**Note#2:** For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `Instant` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(instant);
```

You can even convert the object of `OffsetDateTime` and `ZonedDateTime` to an object of `java.util.Date`, as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(odt.toInstant());
```

&

```
Date date = Date.from(zdt.toInstant());
```

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

### Why did your `java.util.Date` object print the India date and time?

A `java.util.Date` object simply represents the number of ***milliseconds*** since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT (or UTC). Since it does not hold any timezone information, its [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--) function applies the JVM's timezone to return a `String` in the format, `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`, derived from this ***milliseconds*** value. To get the `String` representation of the `java.util.Date` object in a different format and timezone, you need to use `SimpleDateFormat` with the desired format and the applicable timezone e.g.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
String strDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(strDate);
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = sdf.parse("2013-09-29T18:46:19Z");

        // In JVM's timezone and default format as returned by Date#toString
        System.out.println(date);

        // In UTC and custom format
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Etc/UTC"));
        String strDate = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(strDate);

        // In India and custom format
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));
        strDate = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println(strDate);
    }
}
```

**Output (my timezone is Europe/London):**

```
Sun Sep 29 19:46:19 BST 2013
2013-09-29T18:46:19Z
2013-09-30T00:16:19+05:30
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/PHsXel)

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 5):

**For Java 8:**
You can use inbuilt `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` to reduce any chance of typos, 
like

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME;
```

ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME represents `2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]` is one of the bundled standard DateTime formats provided by Oracle [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: On Android, this needs the app to run above API 26

Comment: @RocBoronat Or desugaring. Or ThreeTenABP. It's certainly worth considering for lower API levels too.

Answer (score 3):

**Reference Examples of existing formatters:**

```
String date1 = "2022-06-19T01:26:05.000+00:00"; 
// internally using DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME
System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse(date1));

//internally using DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(date1));

String date2 = "2022-06-19T01:26:05"; 
//internally using DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(date2)); 

String date3 = "2022-06-19T01:26:05.00Z"; 
//internally using DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT
System.out.println(Instant.parse(date3));
```

**Output:**

```
2022-06-19T01:26:05Z
2022-06-19T01:26:05Z
2022-06-19T01:26:05
2022-06-19T01:26:05Z
```