# Unable to parse String using Java Date parser

Tags: java, datetime, date-format

I was parsing a datetime string using this: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html but somehow i was getting runtime error on parsing: https://ideone.com/gpFqwp

Can anyone point me to my mistake here?

```
static String date = "2015-09-17T08:22:49Z";
public static DateFormat inputDatetimeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
public static DateFormat displayDateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.println(displayDateFormat.format(inputDatetimeFormatter.parse(date)));
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168647/java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sssz-simple/20168693

Comment: Thanks. Wonder why thats not mentioned in official doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateFormat inputDatetimeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");
```

See javadoc for [SimpleDateFormat in Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

or use

```
 DateFormat inputDatetimeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
```

See javadoc for [SimpleDateFormat in Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

here is a [sample](https://ideone.com/WcN46o)

Answer (score 0):

Change `inputDatetimeFormatter` to `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");`. Then it will run fine.

EDIT : What is the purpose of the `Z` at the end of your `date` string?
Is it just a letter that you always want to be there?

Then you will have to change `inputDatetimeFormatter` to the above.
If the purpose of `Z` is for the time zone then your `date` string is wrong (shouldn't contain `Z` but a time zone, e.g. `-0800`).

Then it would give :

```
static String date = "2015-09-17T08:22:49-0800"; // Replace -0800 by wanted time zone
public static DateFormat inputDatetimeFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"); // Now you can use Z (instead of 'Z') to indicate that the time zone is following
```