# how to convert the json string date to Date format in android

Tags: android

{

```
"time_slots": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "from_time": "2000-01-01T09:00:00.000Z",
  "to_time": "2000-01-01T10:00:00.000Z",
  "created_at": "2016-05-27T08:09:05.979Z",
  "updated_at": "2016-05-27T08:09:05.979Z",
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "from_time": "2000-01-01T10:00:00.000Z",
  "to_time": "2000-01-01T11:00:00.000Z",
  "created_at": "2016-05-27T08:17:43.121Z",
  "updated_at": "2016-05-27T08:17:43.121Z",
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "from_time": "2000-01-01T13:00:00.000Z",
  "to_time": "2000-01-01T14:00:00.000Z",
  "created_at": "2016-05-27T08:18:06.251Z",
  "updated_at": "2016-05-27T08:18:06.251Z",
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 4,
  "from_time": "2000-01-01T14:00:00.000Z",
  "to_time": "2000-01-01T15:00:00.000Z",
  "created_at": "2016-05-27T08:18:34.752Z",
  "updated_at": "2016-05-27T08:18:34.752Z",
  "status": true
}
```

]
}
can any one please help how to convert json string time to Time format in android.I tried to convert using simple date format  SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-ddTh:m:s"); but its not working.Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Please atleast do some searching before asking

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168647/java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sssz-simple

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" - SimpleDateFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168647/java-text-parseexception-unparseable-date-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sssz-simple)

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
Date myDate = myFormat.parse("your date string here");
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.parse( "2016-05-27T08:17:43.121Z" )
```

## Details

> json string time

No such thing as "JSON time". What you have is strings in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

The `Z` on the end is pronounced [`Zulu`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones), and means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

> Time format in android.

No such thing as "Android time format". You can use any format that is appropriate to your user’s human language and cultural norms. See the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html?is-external=true) class, and in particular, its [`ofLocalized…`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDateTime-java.time.format.FormatStyle-) methods.

> SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-ddTh:m:s")

That class is part of the troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. They were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

The *java.time* classes use the standard ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2016-05-27T08:17:43.121Z" ) ;
```

To see this same moment in the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region (a time zone), apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;   // Always use proper time zone names in `Continent/Region` format, never pseudo-zones like `PDT`, `CST`, `IST`, etc. 
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;  // Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
String dt_str = "2000-01-01T13:00:00.000Z";  
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");  
try {  
   Date date = format.parse(dt_str);  
   System.out.println(date);  
} catch (ParseException e) {  
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
  e.printStackTrace();  
}
```