# How To properly format Date string from DateTimePicker for parsing by SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, parse-platform, datetimepicker

I am using the [jQuery DateTimePicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) to get a user-selected date and time (with timezone) from a `JSP` form I created. I'm new to `Javascript` so I may be making a mistake in my approach or code. So if I am, please point it out so I can learn.

The date/time `jQuery` selector shows and works as expected, however I need to send its data to a Java servlet I created, which then creates a new Parse Object in my Parse.com database with that date data. According to [Parse's docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#objects-types), the Date field stored for an object is as follows:

> "The Date type contains a field iso which contains a UTC timestamp
>   stored in ISO 8601 format with millisecond precision:
>   YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.MMMZ."

Essentially, I need to reformat the returned date from the form to match Parse's requirements, which I will do with SimpleDateFormat in my servlet. (I've been able to do that with a `Date object` in Java already, so an alternative solution would be to send the Date data as a Date object straight from the `jsp`. If that is possible, please tell me how.)

I matched up the [formatting for SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with the [DatePicker format](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/jQuery-UI-Changing-the-date-format-for-Datepicker-P1023.html) and [TimePicker format](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#tp-formatting) so that SimpleDateFormat would be able to parse and reformat the Date string without a problem into a Date object in my servlet. (Curse whoever allowed using such a variety of formats when dealing with dates and times instead of using one universal format... T_T) (Maybe this is the part I did wrong? Anyone willing to double-check?)
So I changed the format in my `DateTimePicker` to match up with SimpleDateFormat's, while retaining user readability:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#timezone_datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy', 
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm Z',
        onClose: function (dateText) {
            $(this).datetimepicker.formatTime('HH:mmZ', dateText);
            }
    });
});
```

The function at `onClose` is my attempt to match the format to SimpleDateFormat's with exact precision before it is sent to the `servlet`. I based it on the utility function mentioned in the [TimePicker's examples:](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#tp-examples)

> Use the utility function to format your own time. $.datepicker.formatTime(format, time, options)

```
$('#utility_example_2').text(
$.datepicker.formatTime('HH:mm z', { hour: 14, minute: 36, timezone: '+2000' }, {})
```

);

Regardless of my numerous attempts and variations, **this is the part where it fails** and I need help with. When I try to parse the passed over Date string with `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm z");       
SimpleDateFormat formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy'T'HH:mmz");
try {
        //datePicked and datePickedFormatted are global Date variables
        datePicked = formatter1.parse(request.getParameter("sendTime"));
        datePickedFormatted = formatter2.parse(datePicked.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        System.out.println("Date formatter failed to parse chosen sendTime.");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get this error in my log:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "08-22-2014 05:18 -04:00"

Why is it still being sent to the servlet formatted like that, when I try to format it to match SimpleDateFormat's? Why won't SimpleDateFormat accept it?

I even tried to parse the date string with [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/index.html) instead of using SimpleDateFormat, but even that didn't work:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(request.getParameter("sendTime"));
```

Any help or comments would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use uppercase 'Z' instead of lowercase 'z'? Or guess it even should be 'X'

Comment: Uppercase 'Z' failed the same way, and when I use 'X', it passes the first `SimpleDateFormat` formatter, so it does accept the date string from the form. However the second formatter fails with this date instead: `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri Aug 22 04:28:00 EDT 2014"`. I need it in the second formatter's format to be able to store it in my Parse.com database.

Comment: Why you have T in your pattern? I think that is giving an exception.

Comment: Use this in second formater 'EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy'

Comment: @sandris Parse seems to require it - without it, Parse's server rejects it. See the answer for a question I asked in the past: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25201814/java-send-date-object-as-jsonobject-through-parse-com-rest-api).

Comment: @birya I used your format and it worked. Now is there a way to get that to ISO format so I can send it to Parse? Parse needs it like this: `"2011-08-21T18:02Z"`. If I need it in ISO format anyway then that format for the second converter doesn't really serve a purpose, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem, getting a head start thanks to users' comments. What I did was use `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the format that the date string was arriving in, into a `Date object`. I then constructed a `DateTime` object ([Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/index.html)) with that `Date object`:

```
datePicked = formatter1.parse(request.getParameter("sendTime"));
DateTime dt = new DateTime(datePicked);
```

`DateTime` defaults to `UTC format` and `ISO-8601`, so the `.toString()` method for it is accepted by Parse.com's database without a problem. This is the final code in the end which works:

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm X");       
    try {
        datePicked = formatter1.parse(request.getParameter("sendTime"));
        System.out.println("Retrieved and formatted dateTime: " + datePicked.toString());
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        System.out.println("Date formatter failed to parse chosen sendTime.");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    DateTime dt = new DateTime(datePicked);
```