# Wrong time after conversion

Tags: android

I get wrong time after conversion. This is my code to converse:

```
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

this is time which I try to converse: `2000-01-01T12:35:00Z` and still get 12:35:00. On iOS I get 13:35:00. Any idea why?

Comment: maybe it is a timezone issue ?

Comment: on phone with android I have the same time like on phone with iOS

Comment: So which behaviour is wrong? iOS or Android?

Comment: android. I should get 13:35:00

Comment: am i wrong? 01:35 is 13:35.. 12:35 should be 00:35 (AM) or 12:35 (PM)..

Comment: maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112357/java-simpledateformatyyyy-mm-ddthhmmssz-gives-timezone-as-ist

Comment: dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); is solution. Thx.