# How set the default time zone in Intl MessageFormatter

Tags: php, intl

I'm using php intl MessageFormatter for translation. In some phrases I'm using date formatting, for example: some text {0,date,dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm}

So, I can't understand, how set the default time zone for it. This ignores php.ini date.timezone and date_default_timezone_set...
Thanks!

Comment: You can see as follows:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112357/java-simpledateformatyyyy-mm-ddthhmmssz-gives-timezone-as-ist
maybe this can help you!

Comment: @Cmder桥. That link is about using client side Java, whereas the OP is using server-side PHP.