# Android datetime parse issue

Tags: android, datetime

dateString: 2016-08-29T11:39:52.2133065

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    try {
      Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
      return dateFormat.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
       Log.e(TAG, "Unable to parse date " + e);
    }
```

The string needs to be converted into `2016-08-29 11:39` but I am getting parse exception.

Comment: This can be solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/19112487/5291413

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'") gives timezone as IST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112357/java-simpledateformatyyyy-mm-ddthhmmssz-gives-timezone-as-ist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format passed to the date formatter should correspond to the format of the string to be parsed. In the case of "2016-08-29T11:39:52.2133065" the date formatter should be:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
```

You will also need a new formatter where you specify the output format:

```
SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
```

Use them like this:

```
Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
return newFormat.format(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,remove **T** in your dateString,

```
                String dateString ="2016-08-29T11:39:52.2133065";
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
                try {
                    Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
                    dateFormat.format(date);
                    Log.e("Log",""+dateFormat.format(date));
                } catch (ParseException e)  {           
                        Log.e("GridActivity", "Unable to parse date " + e);
                }
```