# How do I convert an ISO 8601 date time String to java.time.LocalDateTime?

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I am reading data from Wikidata. They represent their point in time property, P585 using ISO 8601 spec. However, the same beings with a +.

If I were using Joda then converting the String to joda dateTime would have been very simple.

```
new DateTime(dateTime, DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

However, when I do `LocalDateTime.parse("+2017-02-26T00:00:00Z")` I get an error saying can't parse the character at index 0. Is there a reason for this in Java 8. Joda does it pretty easily without any errors.

I also tried `LocalDateTime.parse("+2017-02-26T00:00:00Z", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)` but in vain.

How do we get around the Plus sign without having to remove it by string manipulation?

Comment: Can you just trim off leading plus sign before parsing? Try parsing `str.replaceAll("^\\+", "")`.

Comment: What is the meaning of "+" in this format?

Comment: Plus means the year is signed.

Comment: Yes I could trim of the plus but don't want to since joda.time can easily parse this. I expect java.time to take care of this.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the wrong type to use here. Use an `OffsetDateTime` (or may consider `Instant`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Java's `DateTimeFormatter` class may be of help. Here is some sample code that I believe addressses your problem (or at least gives you something to think about):

```
class DateTimeTester {
  ---
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("+yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
        .withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse("+2017-02-26T01:02:03Z", formatter);
    System.out.println(date);
  }
}
```

Refer to the section called ***Patterns for Formatting and Parsing*** in the [javadoc for DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for details about the format-string passed to `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern()`.

Something to note:

[Wikidata's list of available data types](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:ListDatatypes) says about the `time` data type:

"explicit value for point in time, represented as a timestamp ***resembling*** ISO 8601, e.g. +2013-01-01T00:00:00Z. **The year is always signed and padded to have between 4 and 16 digits**.".

So Wikidata's `time` data type only *resembles* ISO 8601.

If your code needs to handle negative years (before year 0), you will need to adjust my suggested solution accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This makes sense. I expected baba.time to take care of this automatically without the DataFormatter just like how joda.time does. Nevertheless thanks for the explanation and answer. How do I mark this as a correct answer?

Comment: I think you could replace those format strings with DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME

Comment: @user2725919 No that will not work. It neither takes the leading `+` nor the trailing `Z` into account. I get `DateTimeParseException: Text '+2017-02-26T01:02:03Z' could not be parsed at index 0`.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41993463/10819573) is wrong for three reasons:

1. The given date-time string `+2017-02-26T00:00:00Z` does not represent a `LocalDateTime`. It represents an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).
2. It uses a `+` sign with the pattern which means the pattern will fail to parse a date-time with a negative year.
3. [`'Z'` is not the same as `Z`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67953075/10819573).

You can create the required `DateTimeFormatter` using the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` as shown below:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4, 4, SignStyle.ALWAYS)
                .appendPattern("-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
                .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("+2017-02-26T00:00:00Z", parser);
        System.out.println(odt);

        // If you want a LocalDateTime, you can get it from `odt`
        LocalDateTime ldt = odt.toLocalDateTime();
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2017-02-26T00:00Z
2017-02-26T00:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/QwJ5gV)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: valid points on accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution can be :

```
LocalDateTime.parse(yourDate, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
```

Don't forget to manage the `DateTimeParseException` in the case of a non supported date format

Comment: This doesn’t seem to work. With the string from the question, `"+2017-02-26T00:00:00Z"`, I get `DateTimeParseException: Text '+2017-02-26T00:00:00Z' could not be parsed at index 0`.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't notice the `+` sign in front of the year after reading the ISO8601 in the title  You would need one of the custom `DateTimeFormatter`s above.