# Java getTime() returns null from formatted String

Tags: java, android, date, nullpointerexception

I have:

```
String stringDate = "2017-02-16T15:00:00Z"
```

I want to convert this into a Date and after it i want to be converted to Long. Here is my code:

```
 private void normalizeDate(ContentValues values) {
    // normalize the date value
    if (values.containsKey(SmogContract.MeasurementEntry.COLUMN_FROM_DATE_TIME)) {
        Date date = convertDateFromStringToDate(values.getAsString(SmogContract.MeasurementEntry.COLUMN_FROM_DATE_TIME));
        long fromDateValue = date.getTime();
        values.put(SmogContract.MeasurementEntry.COLUMN_FROM_DATE_TIME, SmogContract.normalizeDate(fromDateValue));
    }
    if (values.containsKey(SmogContract.MeasurementEntry.COLUMN_TILL_DATE_TIME)) {
        long fromDateValue = values.getAsLong(SmogContract.MeasurementEntry.COLUMN_TILL_DATE_TIME);
        values.put(SmogContract.MeasurementEntry.COLUMN_TILL_DATE_TIME, SmogContract.normalizeDate(fromDateValue));
    }
}

private Date convertDateFromStringToDate(String stringDate){
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    Date convertedFromStringDate = null;
    try {
        convertedFromStringDate = format.parse(stringDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return convertedFromStringDate;
}
```

Here is the exception that i am getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference
                 at com.example.marcin.smog_mapa.data.SmogProvider.normalizeDate(SmogProvider.java:109)
                 at com.example.marcin.smog_mapa.data.SmogProvider.insert(SmogProvider.java:85)
                 at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:263)
                 at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:163)
                 at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
```

Comment: Please have a look at console. Surprise !!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112357/java-simpledateformatyyyy-mm-ddthhmmssz-gives-timezone-as-ist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'") gives timezone as IST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112357/java-simpledateformatyyyy-mm-ddthhmmssz-gives-timezone-as-ist)

Comment: Well, with that input, this should be fine since you don't really have a `Z` value.

Comment: I don't know what you expect but it returns: `Thu Feb 16 15:00:00 PKT 2017` not null at all

Comment: I got a correct result using your method, and no exception thrown. Could you provide more information about how your method `convertDateFromStringToDate` is used? e.g. your full program.

Comment: @AxelH I have made an edit of the question

Comment: You exception message is not the root cause. Please provide the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

The `format.parse(...)` statement fails with a `ParseException`, leaving `convertedFromStringDate` at `null`.
Check your console for the stack trace and make sure `stringDate` has the correct format.

Comment: This is a String which i get from an API response

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it was just an silly mistake in the method.

Here is it done correctly:

```
private void normalizeDate(ContentValues values) {
    // normalize the date value
    if (values.containsKey(SmogContract.MeasurementEntry.COLUMN_FROM_DATE_TIME)) {
        Date date = convertDateFromStringToDate(values.getAsString(SmogContract.MeasurementEntry.COLUMN_FROM_DATE_TIME));
        Log.d("ConvertedDate: ", String.valueOf(date.getTime()));
        long fromDateValue = date.getTime();
        values.put(SmogContract.MeasurementEntry.COLUMN_FROM_DATE_TIME, SmogContract.normalizeDate(fromDateValue));
    }
    if (values.containsKey(SmogContract.MeasurementEntry.COLUMN_TILL_DATE_TIME)) {
        Date date = convertDateFromStringToDate(values.getAsString(SmogContract.MeasurementEntry.COLUMN_TILL_DATE_TIME));
        Log.d("ConvertedDate: ", String.valueOf(date.getTime()));
        long fromDateValue = date.getTime();
        values.put(SmogContract.MeasurementEntry.COLUMN_TILL_DATE_TIME, SmogContract.normalizeDate(fromDateValue));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem come from

```
long fromDateValue = values.getAsLong(SmogContract.MeasurementEntry.COLUMN_TILL_DATE_TIME);
```

Where `values` is a `ContentValues` instance.

[ContentValues.getAsLong](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html#getAsLong(java.lang.String)) return a `null` that you store in a `long`, so it call `Long.longValue()` leading to this `NullPointerException`

This is the risk with this auto-boxing / unboxing, if you have

```
Long wrap_long = null;
long l = wrap_long;
```

This will compile but will throw a NPE at runtime where

```
long l = null;
```

will never compile, for the same reason, a primitive value can't be  `null`

It is good to check the `Long` value for null when you unbox it.