# Convert string to OffsetDateTime in Java

Tags: java, string, date, datetime, java-8

I am trying to convert a string in `OffsetDateTime` but getting below error.

`java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '20150101' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2015-01-01 of type java.time.format.Parsed`

Code : `OffsetDateTime.parse("20150101", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));`

Expected output: `OffsetDateTime object with date 20150101.`

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Thanks,

Comment: Your string date is in different format than the pattern. Should not you use "yyyyMMdd" format?

Comment: Sorry for typo, updated my question. I am passing "yyyyMMdd" only but getting mentioned error.

Comment: I think your date and formatter have to also specify offset like this date: 2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00 . See the part after + sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your reply. 
Earlier I was using joda datetime (look at below method) to handle date and datetime both but I wanted to use Java8 libraries instead of the external libraries.

```
static public DateTime convertStringInDateFormat(String date, String dateFormat){
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(dateFormat);
return formatter.parseDateTime(date);
}
```

I was expecting same with OffsetDateTime but got to know we can use ZonedDateTime or OffsetDateTime if we want to work with a date/time in a certain time zone.
As I am working on Period and Duration for which LocalDate can help.

String to DateTime:

```
LocalDate date =
LocalDate.parse("20150101", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));
```

LocalDate to desired string format:

```
String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
date.atStartOfDay().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat));
```

Comment: Correct understanding. Tip: on that last line, I recommend **always passing an explicit `ZoneId` to that `atStartOfDay`** call. Example: `.atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( " Africa/Lagos" ) )`  Otherwise you are implicitly getting the JVM’s current default time zone. Better to be explicit about your desired/expected time zone. And, that default can be changed at any moment *during* runtime by any code in the JVM, so the default is unreliable. For example, given what you said in you Question, you would be getting the start of a Chicago day rather than the start of a Lagos day.

Comment: Another note, `LocalDate` is for `Period` as that class represents a span of time with a granularity of years, months, days. But a `Duration` is a span of time as a total number of seconds plus a fraction of a second in nanoseconds. So a `Duration` applies to date-time values such as `Instant`, `OffsetDateTime`, and `ZonedDateTime` rather than a date-only `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 14):

`OffsetDateTime` represents a date-time with an offset , for eg.

> 2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00

The text you are trying to parse does not conform to the requirements of `OffsetDateTime.` 
See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html

The string being parsed neither contains the ZoneOffset nor time. From the string and the pattern of the formatter, it looks like you just need a LocalDate. So, you could use :

```
LocalDate.parse("20150101", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));
```

Answer (score 2):

As Pallavi said correctly OffsetDateTime makes only in the context of a offset.
Hence to go from a date string to an OffsetDateTime, you need a timezone!

Here is the recipe. Find yourself a Timezone, UTC or other.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("UTC");   // Or another geographic: Europe/Paris
ZoneId defaultZone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
```

Make the LocalDateTime, works the same with LocalDate.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");    
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-01-28T14:29:10.212", formatter);
```

An offset makes only sense for a timezone and a time.
For instance, Eastern Time hovers between GMT-4 and GMT-5 depending on the time of year.

```
ZoneOffset offset = zoneId.getRules().getOffset(dateTime);
```

Finally you can make your OffsetDateTime from both the time and the offset:

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.of(dateTime, offset);
```

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 2):

### `Z` not literal

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44354091/10819573) has a serious problem: it uses the literal, `'Z'` in the pattern to specify the UTC offset. `'Z'` is just a character literal whereas `Z` is the timezone designator for zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the UTC offset (+00:00 hours). Check **[`'Z'` is not the same as `Z`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67953075/10819573)** to learn more about it.

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" )  // Z is a formatting code, not a string literal.
```

### `DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE`

Apart from this, the parsing code can be improved by using the predefined formatter, [`DateTimeFormatter#BASIC_ISO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE).

```
LocalDate.parse("20150101", DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)
```

### Specify time zone

Also, one should always specify a timezone explicitly; otherwise, the JVM will use the system's default timezone, a common cause of many problems developers face.

**Demo:**

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("20150101", DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);

        // Convert date into a ZonedDateTime at the start of the day in the 
        // desired timezone e.g. ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC")
        ZonedDateTime zdt = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));

        // Convert the obtained ZonedDateTime into an OffsetDateTime
        OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime();
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2015-01-01T00:00Z
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/HI7GuU)

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**

Comment: Perhaps better to use `ZoneOffset.UTC` constant rather than `ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC")`. Or choose some arbitrary time zone as an example.

Comment: Thanks, @BasilBourque for the valuable edits and the recommendation to use `ZoneOffset.UTC`. I wrote the code in my IDE using `ZoneOffset.UTC` but changed it to `ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC")` before posting my answer. The reason I did so because many developers do not realise that [`ZoneOffset` extends `ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) and get confused with `ZoneId` in [`LocalDate#atStartOfDay(ZoneId)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-).

Answer (score 1):

Use a LocalDate instead of offsetDatetime for your case as you want to parse only date (no time/offset). The usage of offsetDatetime is very well discussed [here](http://logicbig.com/how-to/code-snippets/jcode-java-8-date-time-api-offsetdatetime-parse/)

Comment: You may then use for example `atStartOfDay().atOffset(yourDesiredOffset)` to convert into an `OffsetDateTime`. Offset could be for instance `ZoneOffset.UTC`. It’s a good thing that the date and time classes often force you to be specific about what you want instead of giving you default values that may not match your needs.