# Convert String without ZonedId to OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, datetime, timezone-offset, zoneddatetime

I would like to convert an String to OffsetDateTime datatype. The string has the following shape:

```
  2017-11-27T19:06:03
```

I've tried two approaches:

**Approach 1**

```
    public static OffsetDateTime convertString(String timestamp) {
        java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatter = new java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .append(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .appendLiteral('T')
            .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
            .toFormatter();


        return OffsetDateTime.parse(timestamp, formatter);
    }
```

**Approach 2:**

```
    public static OffsetDateTime convertString(String timestamp) {
        java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter parser = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        java.time.LocalDateTime dt = java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(timestamp, parser);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(dt, java.time.ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        return OffsetDateTime.from(zdt);
    }
```

First approach does not work since it complains the following:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-11-27T19:02:42' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2017-11-27T19:02:42 of type java.time.format.Parsed

For my understanding it comes from the fact that the string does not have ZoneId.  How can I overwrite, on the formatter, the ZoneId so to ignore it?

The second approach comes [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297939/convert-string-to-offsetdatetime-in-java) and works but it requieres 2 additional conversions, I would like to avoid those additional conversions.

Any help is going to be appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected result? Since the string hasn’t got a time zone or offset in it, you need to decide an offset to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get an `OffsetDateTime` from a string with no offset or time zone, you need to decide an offset or a way to get one. The most obvious way is if you know in which time zone the date-time is to be interpreted. For example:

```
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(timestamp)
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Chongqing"))
            .toOffsetDateTime();
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output using the string from your question:

> 2017-11-27T19:06:03+08:00

Don’t be afraid of the two conversions from `LocalDateTime` to `ZonedDateTime` and then to `OffsetDateTime`. With `java.time` they are not only easy to do but also clear to read.

If you know the offset, just use that, then you need only one conversion (I am using a nonsensical offset for the example, so you will have to pick your own):

```
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(timestamp)
            .atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(-36953));
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output:

> 2017-11-27T19:06:03-10:15:53

You may specify your desired offset as for example `ZoneOffset.of("+08:00")` or `ZoneOffset.ofHours(8)`.

But to answer your question (it’s about time now).

> How can I overwrite, on the formatter, the ZoneId so to ignore it?

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, -36953)
            .toFormatter();
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(timestamp, formatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output is the same as the previous one (and again you will need to pick an offset that makes sense in your situation).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've solved this issue by the following code:

```
    public static OffsetDateTime convertString(String timestamp) {
        java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter formatter = new java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .append(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .appendLiteral('T')
            .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendLiteral(':')
            .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
            .toFormatter();

    return LocalDateTime.parse(timestamp, formatter)
            .atOffset(java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC);
    }
```