# How do I parse a java simple date format in R?

Tags: r, date, time

The extra T and Z are throwing me off:

```
strptime("2017-06-08T11:55:53.179000Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```

Returns `NA`

Comment: The answer by @Psidom fixes the seconds part (which gets rid of the NA response). However,  I don't see any answer that deals with the Z.  I think that part of the problem is that Z is not a proper ISO  time zone.  It is US Military time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the `anytime()` function of the [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package:

```
R> anytime("2017-06-08T11:55:53.179000Z")
[1] "2017-06-08 11:55:53.178 CDT"
R>
```

The whole point of the [anytime](https://cran.r-project.org/package=anytime) package is to parse such *common* formats *without requiring a format*.  Dealing with the trailing `Z` comes for free via the Boost parser.

If you want it interpreted as UTC use the corresponding `utctime()` package:

```
R> utctime("2017-06-08T11:55:53.179000Z")
[1] "2017-06-08 06:55:53.178 CDT"
R>
```

If you want it stored as UTC, set the timezone accordingly:

```
R> utctime("2017-06-08T11:55:53.179000Z", tz="UTC")
[1] "2017-06-08 11:55:53.178 UTC"
R>
```

Comment: But it does not appear to have correctly dealt with the Z. Should be [Zulu = GMT](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z)

Comment: It all depends on what exactly you want.  Default is localtime, see my third call in the answer.

Comment: But this answer would force all times to UTC, not just ones ending in Z .  Since the data specifies Z, it would be nice to be able to have the code figure that out.

Comment: See the documentation of the package which points that Boost itself only uses the timezone symbol for _output_ and does not support parsing it.

Comment: Of course.  `anytime` should have been my first thought!

Answer (score 1):

According to `?strptime`, you can parse it with `%OS` parameter by setting the `digits.secs` option:

> Specific to R is %OSn, which for output gives the seconds truncated to
>   0 <= n <= 6 decimal places (and **if %OS is not followed by a digit, it
>   uses the setting of getOption("digits.secs"), or if that is unset, n =
>   0**). Further, for strptime %OS will input seconds including fractional
>   seconds. Note that %S does not read fractional parts on output.

```
options(digits.secs = 6)
strptime("2017-06-08T11:55:53.179000Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ")
# [1] "2017-06-08 11:55:53.179 EDT"
```

Comment: That gets by the NA,  but it is also getting EDT,   not Zulu.

Comment: @G5W I guess `Z` doesn't stand for timezone here, so you can parse it as any time zone by pass the timezone to the `tz` parameter? Something like `strptime("2017-06-08T11:55:53.179000Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ", tz = "UTC")`?

Comment: I thought it meant [Zulu = GMT](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z)

Comment: @G5W Maybe we should wait for OP to clairfy this, I doubt Z stands for `Zulu` here. You can see [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/SimpleDateFormat.htm) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). It doesn't seem like it's a standard way to use `Z` as the short cut for `GMT`.

Comment: It is standard in the US Military See [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/z)  But I concur about getting a response from the OP.

Comment: I actually think the `Z` stands for UTC, but am not 100% sure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112357/java-simpledateformatyyyy-mm-ddthhmmssz-gives-timezone-as-ist

Comment: AHA! Z stands for `Zulu` time, or UTC: "UTC time is also known as Zulu time, since Zulu is the NATO phonetic alphabet word for Z".  This is a little confusing, lol.