# Java: Adding TimeZone to DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, datetime

The LocalDateTime API gives the possibility to add the TimeZone Name by using the key "z" in the formatter. I get an exception adding this key and don't understand why. I'm looking for something like this example '`11:59:22 PM GMT`' and not '`**... UMT+2**`'.

My Code:

```
public class TimeZone
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a z");
        System.out.println(now.format(formatter));
    }
}
```

The Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to extract value: class java.time.LocalDateTime
at java.time.format.DateTimePrintContext.getValue(Unknown Source)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$ZoneTextPrinterParser.format(Unknown Source)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$CompositePrinterParser.format(Unknown Source)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.formatTo(Unknown Source)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.format(Unknown Source)
at java.time.LocalDateTime.format(Unknown Source)
at tz.TimeZone.main(TimeZone.java:12)
```

Here is the DateTimeFormatter API part:

```
All letters 'A' to 'Z' and 'a' to 'z' are reserved as pattern letters. The following pattern letters are defined: 
  Symbol  Meaning                     Presentation      Examples
  ------  -------                     ------------      -------
   G       era                         text              AD; Anno Domini; A
   u       year                        year              2004; 04
   y       year-of-era                 year              2004; 04
   D       day-of-year                 number            189
   M/L     month-of-year               number/text       7; 07; Jul; July; J
   d       day-of-month                number            10

   Q/q     quarter-of-year             number/text       3; 03; Q3; 3rd quarter
   Y       week-based-year             year              1996; 96
   w       week-of-week-based-year     number            27
   W       week-of-month               number            4
   E       day-of-week                 text              Tue; Tuesday; T
   e/c     localized day-of-week       number/text       2; 02; Tue; Tuesday; T
   F       week-of-month               number            3

   a       am-pm-of-day                text              PM
   h       clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12)  number            12
   K       hour-of-am-pm (0-11)        number            0
   k       clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-24)  number            0

   H       hour-of-day (0-23)          number            0
   m       minute-of-hour              number            30
   s       second-of-minute            number            55
   S       fraction-of-second          fraction          978
   A       milli-of-day                number            1234
   n       nano-of-second              number            987654321
   N       nano-of-day                 number            1234000000

   V       time-zone ID                zone-id           America/Los_Angeles; Z; -08:30
   z       time-zone name              zone-name         Pacific Standard Time; PST
   O       localized zone-offset       offset-O          GMT+8; GMT+08:00; UTC-08:00;
   X       zone-offset 'Z' for zero    offset-X          Z; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15;
   x       zone-offset                 offset-x          +0000; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15;
   Z       zone-offset                 offset-Z          +0000; -0800; -08:00;
```

Can anyone see what the problem is?

Comment: Some find the “local” in the class names `LocalDate`, `LocalTime` and `LocalDateTime` confusing. It means “without time zone”. If you want a date-time object that “knows” in *which* time zone it is local, use `ZonedDateTime`.

Answer (score 22):

[`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) has two fields of type `LocalDate` and `LocalTime`.
[`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) has fields `day`, `month`, and `year`.
[`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) has fields `hour`, `minute`, `second`, and `nano`.

Nowhere in that is a time zone given. Which is by nature, since the javadoc of `LocalDateTime` says:

> A date-time without a time-zone

So, if the "local" date/time value is already representing a time in UTC, and you want it formatted saying so, you have multiple options:

- Change the `LocalDateTime` to a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) by calling [`atZone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-):

  ```
  System.out.println(time.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                         .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a z")));
  ```
- Specify an override time zone in the formatter by calling [`withZone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone-java.time.ZoneId-):

  ```
  System.out.println(time.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a z")
                                                  .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)));
  ```
- Format with a literal `Z` character:

  ```
  System.out.println(time.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a 'Z'")));
  ```

All three of the above outputs:

`11:59:22 PM Z`

---

Now, if the "local" date/time is really in a different time zone, you can use either of the first two, and just specify the actual zone.

E.g. if time zone is `-04:00`, use `ZoneOffset.ofHours(-4)`, and you'll get:

`11:59:22 PM -04:00`

Or if you are in New York, use `ZoneId.of("America/New_York")`, and you'll get:

`11:59:22 PM EDT`

If the "local" date/time is for New York, but you want formatted text to be UTC, use both at the same time, i.e.

```
System.out.println(time.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))
                       .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a z")
                                                .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)));
```

With that, you get the time converted to:

`03:59:22 AM Z`

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer. I ll try your solutions! That question seems to bring up the question of how the computer actually gets it's numbers for the time. So if i want to show a different time zone from my locale I have to manually calculate the offset?

Comment: @Herr.Roehrig If you want current time in New York, regardless of what your default time zone is, call `LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))`. So if you learned anything from my answer, you'd figure out that getting current time in UTC, you do `LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of(ZoneOffset.UTC))`.

Comment: @Herr.Roehrig Talking about [`LocalDateTime.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now--): Since you called the no-arg overload of `now()`, the time is in the default time zone, i.e. in the [`ZoneId.systemDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault--) time zone, so that is the time zone you'd want to specify in the code in the answer.

Comment: **Caution**: ['Z' is not the same as Z](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67953075/10819573) which means one can use the 3rd option of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49459222/10819573) only when the required time zone is UTC.

Answer (score 7):

The `LocalDateTime` class does not support time zones; you can use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) instead.

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a z");
System.out.println(now.format(formatter));
```

This no longer throws an exception and prints `06:08:20 PM EDT` for me, but the timezone will differ depending on your location.