# java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to extract ZoneId from temporal

Tags: java, datetime-format, java-time

When I run the first segment, it is perfectly fine and generate an output. but in second case when I run this segment 2, It generates

```
DateTimeException : Unable to extract ZoneId from temporal.
```

***segment 1:***

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL).format(ld));
```

***segment 2:***

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.FULL);
System.out.println(dtf.format(ldt));
```

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49458878/java-adding-timezone-to-datetimeformatter

Answer (score 10):

I think It is a little complicated to explain, because you are mixing between two things `ofLocalizedDate`, `ofLocalizedDateTime` and the `FormatStyle` :

In the first case you are calling `ofLocalizedDate` with the `FormatStyle.FULL` so you are ignoring the time part.

In the second case you are calling `ofLocalizedDateTime` also with `FormatStyle.FULL` which will include all the parts of the date, which is not the case for `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime`.

To be sure lets try with `MEDIUM`, or `SHORT` instead of `FULL` :

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM).format(ldt)
=> 30 déc. 2019 à 14:57:40 - without any exception
```

For more details check the comments here :

```
/**
 * Full text style, with the most detail.
 * For example, the format might be 'Tuesday, April 12, 1952 AD' or '3:30:42pm PST'.
 */
FULL,
/**
 * Long text style, with lots of detail.
 * For example, the format might be 'January 12, 1952'.
 */
LONG,
/**
 * Medium text style, with some detail.
 * For example, the format might be 'Jan 12, 1952'.
 */
MEDIUM,
/**
 * Short text style, typically numeric.
 * For example, the format might be '12.13.52' or '3:30pm'.
 */
SHORT;
```

To resume we can create a this table :

|  | ofLocalizedTime | ofLocalizedDate | ofLocalizedDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **LocalTime** | MEDIUM, SHORT |  |  |
| **LocalDate** |  | FULL, LONG, MEDIUM, SHORT |  |
| **LocalDateTime** | MEDIUM, SHORT | FULL, LONG, MEDIUM, SHORT | MEDIUM, SHORT |
| **ZonedDateTime** | FULL, LONG, MEDIUM, SHORT | FULL, LONG, MEDIUM, SHORT | FULL, LONG, MEDIUM, SHORT |
| **OffsetDateTime** | MEDIUM, SHORT | FULL, LONG, MEDIUM, SHORT | MEDIUM, SHORT |

```
=> FULL, LONG, MEDIUM, SHORT are FormatStyle
```

You can read it as `LocalDateTime` can use `ofLocalizedDate` with all the format styles, and no can't accept any `FormatStyle` with `ofLocalizedDateTime`

Comment: Please explain more detail Why using extra think ZonedDateTime

Comment: @NgSharma ok check my answer now, I think i make it more easy yo be clear

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing "localized" and "local":

- [`ofLocalizedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDateTime-java.time.format.FormatStyle-): Returns a **locale specific** date-time formatter
- [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html): A date-time **without a time-zone**

As you can see, they are two entirely different terms.

Now, try supplying a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) value, so you can see why it wants a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.FULL);
System.out.println(dtf.format(zdt));
```

*Output* (locale: `en_US`, time zone: `America/New_York`)

```
Monday, December 30, 2019 at 8:09:16 AM Eastern Standard Time
```

As you can see, it needs the time zone to know that the time is "Eastern Standard Time".

If you reduce the time style from [`FULL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html#FULL) to [`MEDIUM`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html#MEDIUM), the time zone is no longer needed.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.FULL, FormatStyle.MEDIUM);
System.out.println(dtf.format(ldt));
```

*Output*

```
Monday, December 30, 2019, 8:09:16 AM
```