# How do I print a ZonedDateTime with timezone but without hyphen?

Tags: java, date, datetime

I need to use a date in a URL, therefore the date cannot contain any symbols like hyphen `-` , dash `/` or colon `:`.

I think `20220615T160543Z` is the only suitable format, but the issue is that it is in UTC, but I need it in some other time zone.

Is there anything like `20220615T160543+2:00`, where the `+2:00` part indicates the time zone offset from UTC?

If yes, can I print it out of a `ZonedDateTime` object?

The object I currently have is

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(date.getStartsOn().toInstant(), timezone);
```

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

Thanks for all the responses!

It looks like my suggested approach is not doable, because it could be like `20220615T160543-2:00` where there is a hyphen...

Apparently percentage-encoding is the only way to do it.

Thanks again!

Comment: You do realise percent-encoding is a thing right?

Comment: but what about time zones like `-02:00`?

Comment: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) allows leaving out hyphens and colons as in `20220615T160543+02:00`. It requires two digits hours in the offset but allows leaving out the colon there too, so the offset becomes `+0200` or `+02:00`. And yes, a `DateTimeFormatter` can produce all of that.

Comment: Thanks, @Sweeper, for pointing out the apparent [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). And its solution.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use an Instant? This way you can present it in any timezone you want.

Comment: While a hyphen is allowed in a URL (also @user16320675), a `+` (plus) will be interpreted as a space, so your `20220615T160543+2:00` would not come through intact. Seems you need to go with [percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). `URLEncoder.encode(yourZonedDateTime.toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` gives `2022-06-15T16%3A05%3A43%2B02%3A00`, which should be safe when the other party percent-decodes it at the other end.

Comment: @Ole ?? they want an output without hyphen - I do not know their requirement, what the URL is used for,... - so I asked what is expected for time zones like `-02:00`

Comment: Given an example of the output you'd want for noon, Eastern Daylight Time (United States). The point is, that zone has a negative offset, but you don't want to use the hyphen commonly used to represent that. What do you want?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I print a ZonedDateTime with timezone but without hyphen?

Try it like this.

First, create a `ZonedDateTime` using the example in your question.

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssz");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse("20220615T160543Z",dtf);
```

Then print it with a `ZoneId` as follows to give you your zone.

```
String dt = zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssVV")
           .withZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Qatar")));
System.out.println(dt);
```

prints

```
20220615T190543Asia/Qatar
```

Note:  Unfortunately a small portion of the ZoneId's contain hyphens.  You can see them by doing the following:

```
ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().stream()
           .filter(str->str.contains("-"))
           .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: It’s not perfectly clear, but I read the question as one about formatting and printing rather than parsing. In any case your code is fine for what you are doing.

Comment: I figured I had to parse it to properly format it to include some aspect of a zone. Clearly someone didn't like it,  lol.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks like my suggested approach is not doable, because it could be like `20220615T160543-2:00` where there is a hyphen... Apparently percentage-encoding is the only way to do it. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Please use something like this:

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.of("US/Eastern"));

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHmmssXXX");
        String formattedString = zonedDateTime.format(formatter);
        System.out.println(formattedString);
    }
}
```

Comment: from question: "*... I need it in some other time zone ...*"

Comment: Also as an aside this conversion is wrong: `ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, ZoneId.of("UTC"))`. Just use one of the `ZonedDateTime.now` methods (there are three of them) and save the conversion.

Comment: You can set any time zone that you need

Comment: That is minus symbol for time zone!

Comment: This is an argument about words. When one person calls it a hyphen and another person calls it a minus, it is always the same char. And while allowed in a URL, the questioner did ask to avoid it.

Comment: *`Eskandar Abedini -That is minus symbol for time zone!`*  It's both.  But I doubt the URL parser will care what you call it or how important it is.  It isn't wanted.

Comment: Another option for zone formatting is `yyyyMMddHmmsszzzz` that gives something like this: `20220615221005Central European Summer Time`

Comment: Here [Java: Adding TimeZone to DateTimeFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49458878/java-adding-timezone-to-datetimeformatter) some formatters given, please check `yyyyMMddHmmssz`

Comment: *`20220615221005Central European Summer Time`* yeah, but even though the OP didn’t state that, a space poses problems in a URL too. Also it just could be that the receiver understands `+02:00` but does not understand time zone names.

Comment: Your sample has positive difference with reference time zone and other zones have negative difference.

Comment: Another solution is separating zone part of formatted time and formatting it manually!