# Convert a UTC time to a local current time

Tags: android, kotlin, threetenbp

I am using the followng library `threetenbp`

I am fetching a date/time from our API response which is in string format
The time I am being sent is this `Sep 30, 2023, 4:59:00 PM`

So I need to convert that to the local time zone. Which for me is Asia/Bangkok.

However, if the time is in UTC and in Asia/Bangkok we are 7 hours ahead. After converting the time the time haven't changed

i.e. time from API Response: `Sep 30, 2023, 4:59:00 PM`

So after converting to local Bangkok time I would think it would plus 7 hours. But I am getting the result `2023-09-30 16:59:00` Which is the exactly same time.

Here is the code snippet

```
    val utcFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy, h:mm:ss a")

    // Parse the UTC time string to a LocalDateTime object.
    val utcDateTime = utcFormatter.parse("Sep 30, 2023, 4:59:00 PM")

    // Create a DateTimeFormatter object with the desired local time zone.
    val localFormatter = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
        .withZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Bangkok"))
    val result = localFormatter.format(utcDateTime)


    // The result is the following: 2023-09-30 16:59:00
```

======

```
val utcFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy, h:mm:ss a")
    .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)

val utcDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("Sep 30, 2023, 4:59:00 PM", utcFormatter)
    .atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Bangkok"))

println(utcDateTime)
```

The output is the following:

```
2023-09-30T16:59+07:00[Asia/Bangkok]
```

However, I thought that the output would have had the time adjusted to be 7 hours ahead. Basically, the time is still the same.

So for example if the UTC time is 12:00 PM then the time would be 7 PM in Bangkok.

Comment: The time you are served lacks timezone information so i guess it's assumed it is in the same local TZ, hence no change occurs.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I was thinking the same. How could I change this `Sep 30, 2023, 4:59:00 PM` to add a time zone of UK/England?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49458878/java-adding-timezone-to-datetimeformatter#49459222

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, but your `utcFormatter` is not really a **UTC** formatter, because you didn't specify the timezone anywhere. You can fix your problem with the following code:

```kotlin
val utcFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy, h:mm:ss a")
    .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

Or alternatively, leave the formatter as is and then specify the zone when parsing:

```kotlin
val utcDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("Sep 30, 2023, 4:59:00 PM", utcFormatter)
    .atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
```

Full example using zoned formatters:

```kotlin
val utcFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy, h:mm:ss a")
    .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)
val localFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    .withZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Bangkok"))

OffsetDateTime.parse("Sep 30, 2023, 4:59:00 PM", utcFormatter)
    .format(localFormatter)
```

Full example by manipulating zones manually:

```kotlin
val inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, yyyy, h:mm:ss a")
val outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

LocalDateTime.parse("Sep 30, 2023, 4:59:00 PM", inputFormatter)
    .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)
    .atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Bangkok"))
    .format(outputFormatter)
```

Comment: I tried your example, but I don't think its working as expected. I have updated my question with some your code. With the output

Comment: You didn't really use code I provided but your own remix of it. First, you seem to mix both my solutions into one. Second, you entirely dropped `localFormatter` which was actually required here. If you only apply small changes suggested by me and leave your other code intact, it should work. Please see updated answer.

Comment: just one question, what is the difference between using zoned formatters and manipulating the zones manually. For both examples you use the ZoneId.of("Asia/Bangkok"). I couldn't see any real difference.

Comment: I think (hope) there is none. Datetime API is very flexible, we can do the same thing in multiple ways. `formatter.parse()`, as in your initial question, is yet another way. Whatever we choose, we need to do essentially the same thing: first parse the date as UTC datetime, then format it to Bangkok datetime.

Comment: If we have some kind of API which always returns dates in the same format/TZ, then for me it makes sense to create a zoned formatter for parsing its outputs and then reuse this formatter. If it is a single use, maybe manipulating the zone directly is easier to read.  We can choose whatever makes more sense for our case.

Comment: Also, it may all seem very complicated, but please note parsing and formatting are separate operations. We can parse in multiple ways and we can format in multiple ways. But both full examples in my answer do the same: they first acquire `OffsetDateTime` in UTC, then format it to Bangkok.