# Angular displaying date with async data through datePipe

Tags: angular, typescript, date, angular-date-format

I'm finally able to display all my async data through this tutorial: https://coryrylan.com/blog/using-angular-forms-with-async-data

The only existing problem is that I collect all the data from my Postgres database and the Dates are saved or arrive after a request like this: `dateOfBirth: "1997-12-24 00:00:00.0"`

I should say that I want to use it to prepopulate input fields for updating a userprofile.

I know that Angular can't handle it like this and I would need an datePipe or something but I really don't know how to use it when I use this to access my data:

```js
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {

      this.buildForm();

      this.user = this.userService.getProfile().pipe(
        tap(user => this.editForm.patchValue(user))
      );
  }

  public buildForm() {
    this.editForm = this.form.group({
      username: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(this.minLength), CustomValidators.validateCharacters], AlreadyTakenValidator.checkUsername(this.registrationService)],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email, CustomValidators.validateCharacters], AlreadyTakenValidator.checkEmail(this.registrationService)],
      oldPassword: ['', [Validators.required], CustomValidators.checkPassword(this.registrationService)],
      newPassword: ['', [Validators.required, CustomValidators.passwordStrength]],
      newPasswordConf: ['', [Validators.required]],
      firstname: ['', [Validators.required, NoWhitespaceValidator()]],
      lastname: ['', [Validators.required, NoWhitespaceValidator()]],
      country: ['', [Validators.required]],
      dateOfBirth: ['', [Validators.required]],
      gender: ['', [Validators.required]],
    }
      , {
        validator: MustMatch('newPassword', 'newPasswordConf')
      })
  }
}

export class User {
    userId: number;
    username: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    token?: string;
    dateOfBirth: Date;
    gender: string;
    country = [] as Array<string>;
    profileImage;
    lastUpdated: Date;
    activated: boolean;
}
```

**Forked StackBlitz of the original idea how it works with a normal date**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2wcq3q?file=src/app/app.component.html

The problematic thing as well will be that I want to change the input type dateFormat through the selected langauge with the i18n-plugin.

In my registration-component I got this working through:

```js
  constructor(
    private translateService: TranslateService,
    private _adapter: DateAdapter<any>
  ) { }

  ngAfterContentChecked() {

    this._adapter.setLocale(this.translateService.currentLang);
```

but with async requested data from the server that does not work. Because nothing gets shown.

**Edit**:
So maybe let me explain something: the problem appears because the server (database in my case postgres) gives something back to the client that it can't use instantly. In Postgres it gets saved as **timestamp without time zone** so e.g.: `2019-06-13 10:26:09.322`

In my server I save the arriving dates of the client like this:

```java
     DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);
     LocalDateTime lu = LocalDateTime.parse(lastUpdated, inputFormatter);
     LocalDateTime dob = LocalDateTime.parse(dateOfBirth, inputFormatter);

     this.dateOfBirth = Date.from(dob.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant()); // both are type Date
     this.lastUpdated = Date.from(lu.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant());
```

I go through many threads on StackOverflow and just read that timezones are annoying as hell and that you should save dates to your database as UTC. But what if I would save them as **timestamp with time zone**? Would this fix the issue that Angular / the client can't handle the arriving dates instantly? I really want to hold the current way I'm prepopulating the input fields but with this idea I can't change the dates before or I just don't know how.

Comment: i think [this](https://blog.angular.io/taking-advantage-of-the-angular-material-datepicker-237e80fa14b3) might guide you to right direction. You need to provide your own `DateAdapter` implementation and use it with `MatDatePicker`

Comment: @ysf that is not really my issue. I mean it's already working when I have a correct date I can switch with my adapter to any time from german to english correctly. But the form of the date that I get is not a real date for Angular and that's why it does not appear there.

Comment: I could now fix it but no way that is a best practice to do this. In my backend API (server) I just format the Date to the format that Angular wants to have, to the **ISO 8601 string** according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112357/java-simpledateformatyyyy-mm-ddthhmmssz-gives-timezone-as-ist/19112487 so before putting the date into the JSONObject of the ResponseEntity I format it `SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);
 sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); jo.put("dateOfBirth", sdf.format(userData.getDateOfBirth()));`