# Java jackson how to deserialize into a Date

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm using `Jackson` to deserialize a date into this attribute:

```
private Date createDate;
```

Part of a payload:

```
"createdDate": "1979-12-05T08:00Z",
```

Getting this error:

> Can not deserialize value of type java.util.Date from String
>   "1979-12-05T08:00Z": not a valid representation (error: Failed to
>   parse Date value '1979-12-05T08:00Z': Can not parse date
>   "1979-12-05T08:00.000Z": while it seems to fit format
>   'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'', parsing fails

What I tried so far was to include this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and also:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ")
private Date createDate;
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: I recommend you use the modern `Instant`, not the poorly designed and long outdated `Date` class. Together with the jsr310 dependency I also expect that this can fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`JsonFormat` annotation should work, you need to only fix your pattern to:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm'Z'")
private Date createDate;
```

Also, you should set time zone on `ObjectMapper` object:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Take a look at:

- [Java SimpleDateFormat(“yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'”) gives timezone as
  IST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112357/java-simpledateformatyyyy-mm-ddthhmmssz-gives-timezone-as-ist)