# How can I convert String to timestamp with timezone?

Tags: java, string, date, parsing

In my Spring Boot project, I have this array of objects (`List<Object> values`)

["2021-06-13T08:50:04.707Z", 3197691, 1933]

The first element is a String and represents a timestamp with timezone.

I can get the first element like this:

```
String time = (String) values.get(0);
```

How can I convert it in date or time format in order to insert in a PostgreSQL table?

Comment: you want to convert it in sql ? If yes then in your query you can write something like this `select '2021-06-13T08:50:04.707Z'::timestamp`

Comment: In which programming language or environment do you wnat to do that?

Comment: Sorry, I am using Java with Spring

Answer (score 3):

The given timestamp string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.

The [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-06-13T08:50:04.707Z");
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-06-13T08:50:04.707Z
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) to learn how to use `OffsetDateTime` with JDBC.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

First thing you must understand the timestamp format, and for your timestamp format is

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
```

Don't forget to add `'T'` and `'Z'`

Then, to convert from string date to Date class you can use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class

```
String dateInString = "2021-06-13T08:50:04.707Z";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateInString);
```

Then use the `data` object to insert to your query. Or if you are using JPA, simply just create the entity and put `data` object to the variable.

Comment: The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html).

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash thank you for the information. Will read more about this.

Comment: rioswarawan - Another thing you should learn is [`'Z'` is not the same as `Z`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67953075/10819573)

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Also quoting the `Z` in the format pattern string is wrong. The `Z` is an offset (of 0) from UTC and needs to be parsed as an offset, or you will get a wrong point in time. Finally lower case `hh` is wrong too.

Comment: (A) *Never* put the `Z` within single-quotes like this `'Z'`. Doing so tells the parser to ignore what is crucial information: An offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. (B) And, as others commented, you are using *terrible* classes that were years ago supplanted by the *java.time* classes. See the modern solution in [Answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67968871/642706).

Comment: Well, thank you guys. Learn so much about this.