# how to change T Z Format 2022-12-08T06:07:34.780Z (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ) come to server but Display DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: android, date, datetime, simpledateformat, date-formatting

- 2022-12-08T06:07:34.780Z
- 12-10-2022     only

  ```
   Utility.log_d("Date12343",orderlist.getCreatedAt());
   /*Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(orderlist.getCreatedAt(), Locale.ENGLISH);
   Log.e("TAG", "formatted string: "+sdf.format(c.getTime()));*/
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
   sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
   try {
       sdf.parse(orderlist.getCreatedAt());
   } catch (ParseException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
  ```

Comment: The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html). Also, ['Z' is not the same as Z](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67953075/10819573).

Comment: Solution using java.time API (the modern date-time API): `OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-01-27T09:27:37Z").format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"))`.

Comment: Your input string, `2022-12-08T06:07:34.780Z`, is in UTC (denoted by the trailing `Z`). Am I assuming correctly that your user wants output in his or her own time zone? It is never the same date in all time zones. At the mentioned point in time it is still  December 7 in California, for example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you have to format using simple date format.

```
String initialStringDate = "2019-01-27T09:27:37Z";
    Locale us = new Locale("US");
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", us);
    try {
        Date date = format.parse(initialStringDate);
        String stringDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", us).format(date);
      

        Log.i("Date", "" + stringDate );
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: here stringDate is your formated date.

Comment: W/System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2022-12-08T07:46:40.043Z"
W/System.err:     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:362)

Comment: String  StartDate = binding.startDate.getText().toString();
                                Log.d("Date1",StartDate);
                               // 08/12/2022

                                String date= StartDate;
                                SimpleDateFormat spf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                                String newDate= spf.format(date);
                                spf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                                String date1 = spf.format(newDate);
                                Log.d("Date2",date1);

Comment: Above code what is the problem

Comment: The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html). Also, ['Z' is not the same as Z](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67953075/10819573).

Comment: Solution using java.time API (the modern date-time API): `OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-01-27T09:27:37Z").format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"))`

Comment: (1) In my most honest opinion helping people how to use `SimpleDateFormat` is doing them an ill favour. No one should use that notoriously troublesome class at all in 2022. (2) The question asked about `2022-12-08T06:07:34.780Z` with three decimals of fraction of second, and your code cannot handle that. You are answering a different question.