# Date decrements by a day when converted to a JSON String - Java

Tags: java, json, date, timezone, objectmapper

We have a method that gets a date from an alpha-numeric String. Say that the String is `Y04051000547GF` the resultant date will be `Tue May 04 00:00:00 IST 2010`.

```
public static Date getDateFromGITID(String gitId) {
    
    Date date = null;
    try {

        String dateInGit = nid.substring(1, 7); //  six characters from the second character

        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        date = format.parse(dateInGit);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        
    }
    
    return date;
}
```

Now, this date is assigned to an attribute of a class `UserInfo`, when we try to convert an object of this class to a JSON the date gets decremented by 1 day!

**Object to JSON string**

```
public static String asJsonString(final Object obj) {
    try {
        return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

**User Info Bean**

```
public class UserInfo {
    
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    Date date;
}
```

This is main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    UserInfo obj = new UserInfo();
    obj.date = getDateFromGITID("Y04051000547GF");
    
    System.out.println(obj.date);

    System.out.println(asJsonString(obj));
}
```

This was the console output

```
Tue May 04 00:00:00 IST 2010
{"dob":"2010-05-03"}
```

You can see that the date is 4th of May 2010, but in JSON it gets decremented by 1 day. We were able to figure out what was causing the issue, the date is printed in **IST** which has a difference of 5 hours and 30 minutes with **UST**. So we added that time before the JSON conversion and the converted time didn't have a change.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    UserInfo obj = new UserInfo();
    obj.dob = getDOBFromNID("Y04051000547GF");
    
    System.out.println(obj.dob);

    obj.dob.setHours(5);
    obj.dob.setMinutes(30);
    obj.dob.setSeconds(00);

    System.out.println(asJsonString(obj));
}
```

**Output**

```
Tue May 04 00:00:00 IST 2010
{"dob":"2010-05-04"}
```

Yes, we have used the deprecated method but it is just for testing. Even if we try to decrease the time by 1 second the issue will come.

**Edit-1 (Found another fix by setting the time zone to the formatter)**

We were able to fix this issue in another way when we set the time zone to **GST** ([Java SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'") gives timezone as IST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19115247/7218656)) for the `DateFormat` inside the `getDateFromGITID` method.

```
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

So the questions are

1. Why is it happening?
2. Is the second way a better fix?
3. Is there any other better fix?

Comment: Best way is to avoid superseded date classes and use `java.time.LocalDate`

Comment: `public static LocalDate getDateFromGITID(String gitId) {DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyy");return LocalDate.parse(gitId.substring(1, 7), dtf); //}`

Comment: I wish @g00se but this is a common bean and it is used in multiple APIs!

Comment: Which `Date` are you using?

Comment: The best way is still to use `LocalDate` internally in your bean. The old-fashioned getter that returns an old-fashoined `Date` representing the start of the date in IST can then return `Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata").toInstant())`. And the JSON can ignore that getter and just use the modern one. You’re fine for the future, and your legacy code will still work.

Comment: *1. Why is it happening?* Because 2010-05-04T00:00 IST is 2010-05-03T18:30 GMT. *2. Is the second way a better fix?* It is less terrible but still terrible. *3. Is there any other better fix?* Yes, use java.time. Convert between `LocalDate` and `Date` for inter-operating with your existing code. Beware of time zone in the conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using terribly flawed date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Specifically, I expect your problem is due to using `java.util.Date#toString` method to generate text. That method lies to you. A `java.util.Date` value represents a date and time as seen with an an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the temporal meridian of UTC. The `toString` method applies the JVM’s current default time zone while generating its textual result.

While well-intentioned, this anti-feature causes endless confusion and pain to Java developers. Avoid this class. Avoid all the legacy date-time classes!

Do all your date-time work using the industry-leading *java.time* classes.

```
String original = "Y04051000547GF" ;
String input = original.substring( 1 , 7 ) ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "ddMMuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

If you must interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert using new methods added to the old classes.

Going from a date to a moment, a specific point on the timeline, requires a time of day, and requires a time zone. I will assume you want the first moment of that date as seen in UTC (an offset of zero).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from( instant ) ;
```

I must note how ill-advised is the use of a date-with-time-and-offset type like `java.util.Date` to represent a date-only value. If possible, consider reworking your codebase to use correct types. For a date-only value, use `java.time.LocalDate` class. `LocalDate` is supported by Java 8+, JDBC 4.2+, Hibernate, Jackson, etc.

Or, [as Commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77203969/date-decrements-by-a-day-when-converted-to-a-json-string-java/77204725#comment136105477_77203969) by Ole V.V., perhaps you mean to get the first moment of the day as seen in a particular time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

The best solution is to educate the publisher of your data to use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for data exchange of date-time values rather than invent their own.

Comment: We are not in a position to change from `util.Date` to `LocalDate`. We were able to find another fix by setting the TimeZone to **GMT**. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19115247/7218656

Comment: Are you saying that you are supposed to fix this problem but you are not allowed to fix the code?

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran Relying on the JVM’s current default time zone is risky and brittle. Any code in any thread of any app within that JVM can, at any moment, change that default. Relying on the JVM’s current default time zone is also unnecessary. Consider again the code in this Answer. It solves your problem completely, without relying on default time zone. With such code, your app will not break suddenly when some sysadmin changes the time zone.